# Assigning one of multiple values based on what exists

Tags: php, python, perl

In Perl, if I want to assign $myVar a value of $var1, $var2, or $var3, based on which one **evaluates to true**, I would code the following:

```
$myVar = $var1 || $var2 || $var3;
```

I am working on separate projects in both Python and PHP, and I have not figured out how to code this situation as concisely in either language.

What is the best way to code this in Python?

What is the best way to code this in PHP?

Comment: You really should not be doing this in Python. If you need names to exist or not exist then you should be using a dict instead.

Comment: As others point out, variables' existence in Python doesn't map well from PHP.  You'll get a better Python answer if you can tell us more about what you mean by "exists".

Comment: In perl, you should really be saying `$myVar = $var1 // $var2 // $var3;`, assuming you are using a modern perl.

Comment: Wes, you explained it wrong and potentially led your answerers on a false path. `||` tests for truth, not for existence. Dave Hilton's comment above tests for definedness.

Comment: Thanks you, Dave and daxim.  I have edited my question to be more correct.  It's good to learn about the "//" operator in Perl.

Comment: **Too Broad** this is asking multiple (potentially opinion-based) questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perl 'autovivifies' variables upon first reference (as far as I remember). Python will raise a `NameError` if a variable doesn't exist. However, you can do something like this.

```
var1 = var2 = var3 = None
# code that might change the value of three variables mentioned above
myvar = var1 or var2 or var3
```

Generally speaking, checking if a variable is defined (and altering the control flow based on that) is a bad thing in Python. You should use a dictionary and keys.

Comment: You've got the terminology wrong in regard to Perl. If you aren't using the `strict` pragma, variables need not be declared before use (just like PHP).  It is considered a best-practice to always use strict, and turn it off as needed over the smallest scope possible.  Autovivification is different.  What it means is that if you have a deep data structure (eg a 4 dimensional array), you can simply say `$array[1][3][2][0] = 5;` without having to do `$array[1] = []; $array[1][3]=[]; $array[1][3][2] = []; $array[1][3][2][0] = 5;`.  All the intermediate structures are autovivified.

Answer (score 2):

In Python, I believe you can say

```
myVar = var1 or var2 or var3
```

The Python documentation describes `x or y` as

> if x is false, then y, else x

**Edit**: theatrus brings up an interesting point - I hadn't even considered that the variables might not be defined.  I found this discussion on the matter:

> Python doesn't have a specific
>   function to test whether a variable is
>   defined, since all variables are
>   expected to have been defined before
>   use - even if initially just assigned
>   the None object. Attempting to access
>   a variable that hasn't previously been
>   defined will raise an exception.
>
> It is generally considered unusual in
>   Python not to know whether a variable
>   has already been defined. But if you
>   are nevertheless in this situation,
>   you can make sure that a given
>   variable is in fact defined (as None,
>   if nothing else) by attempting to
>   access it inside a 'try' block and
>   assigning it the None object should it
>   raise a NameError exception.

So, if you're not guaranteed that the variables exist, and you want to check one by one for both existence and truthiness, you could be in for some messy code.

Comment: This only works when var1/2/3 are declared but possibly False. If var1/2/3 are not declared, it results in a name error.

Comment: That would cause an exception if `var1` didn't *exist*.

Comment: You could check the `locals()` and `globals()` dictionaries to see if the variable is defined but all that is simply not the Python way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you can use [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) to test to see if the variable is set and not null. To achieve what you are looking for you can check whether `$var1`, `$var2` or `$var3` is set, and then set the value to `$myVar`

But beware depending on the condition of which you want to set your `$myVar` to, this would evaluate to true:

```
$str = '';
var_dump(isset($str)); // TRUE
```

Answer (score 1):

In PHP you could do this (assumes the variables are set):

```
$vars = array($var1, $var2, $var3);
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    if ($myvar = $var) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Or, to make it slightly more perly :) :

```
foreach(array($var1,$var2,$var3)as$var)if($myvar=$var)break;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are also [conditional expressions](http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.5.html#pep-308-conditional-expressions) in Python added in Python 2.5:

```
x = true_value if condition else false_value
```

I cannot speak to PHP.

One thing to keep in mind with both languages is that trying to evaluate a variable that does not exist is always going to throw an error. With Python, you could work around this by catching the `NameError` exception that will occur if you attempt this and fallback to a default:

```
>>> try: 
...     myVar = var1 or var2 or var3
... except NameError:
...     myVar = 'default'
... 
>>> myVar
'default'
```

So if `var1`, `var2`, or `var3` are either not set, then `myVar` will receive the fallback value of "default". Otherwise, you'll get the value of whichever var of the set evaluated to `True`.